# Can someone explain the error?

Tags: c, arrays, compiler-errors

I have a C program below and in function `func` there are two `for` loops.  In the first `for` loop, while incrementing the array variable `a` there is no 'lvalue required' error but while incrementing array variable `c` in the second `for` loop, the compiler gives an 'lvalue required' error.  Why?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
void func(char a[],int n);

int main(int argc,char **argv){

    char * s="Happy ,People\n\n";
    func(s,strlen(s));

    return 0;
}

void func(char a[],int n){
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("%c",*a++);      //This works fine — no lvalue error here
    }

    char c[]="Happy ,People\n\n";
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("%c",*c++); // there is error coming here lvalue Required
    }
}
```

Comment: And one recommendation from me -- just use meaningful names for the variables instead of `a[]` and `c[]`. Its a convention anyway :)

Answer (score 4):

In the function, `c` is an array.  The name of an array is a constant.  You can't increment it or decrement it.

Contrary to popular myth, there are differences between arrays and pointers.

And the use of `[]` in function prototypes confuses things because they really identify pointers. You'd get the same result with:

```
void func(char *a, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%c",*a++);
    char c[] = "Happy, People\n\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%c",*c++);
}
```

Comment: +1 I wish I could up-vote this again, just for the mention of the myth.  I continue to see it (the myth) perpetuated, and my only response is "pointers *hold* addresses; arrays *are* addresses." Thank you for mentioning the differences.

Comment: +1 for *And the use of [] in function prototypes confuses things because they really identify pointers* :)

Answer (score 2):

An array is not an lvalue. The name of the array is a pointer constant to the first element of the array. You cannot modify the address to which the array's name points. In following code fragment:

```
char c[]="Happy ,People\n\n";
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
printf("%c",*c++); // there is error coming here lvalue Required
```

When you try `*c++`, you are attempting to modify what `c` points to. Since `c` is a pointer constant, not a variable, you will get the compiler error.

However, when you pass an array to a function, the array "decays" to a pointer, and the pointer to the array is passed by value. The function receives a new pointer with the same value as the original pointer--i.e., a new pointer that points to the same place, which is the first element of the array. Since it's not a constant, that new pointer can be modified to point somewhere else. So `*a++` does not cause a compiler error.